# In .NET C#: Inheriting control Texbox, and Changing the Default BackColor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to inherit class System.Windows.Forms.Textbox,
and change it's default BackColor property to smething else.

What is the best way to do it?

This requires 2 parts:

1) In my inheriting class, where should I put the
**base.BackColor  =Color.FromArgb(0x55,0x55,0xFF);**
line: in the Ctor? in Initialize? Load? some place else? where is the most appropriate..

2) When I set the DefaultValue property, how do I give it a parameter which is a Color type?
If I give an int, like **0x5555FF**, then later on when I am in Visual Studion's Designer,
If I click the Backcolor property on an instance of my control, and then RightClick the property and choose **"Reset"**, then I get an error:
**"Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Drawing.Color'."**

The IDE expects the value in for the DefaultValue attribute to be a Color struct, and not an int..
But I cannot send a Color struct when in the attribute, so what will be the solution?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do that in the constructor, yes
2) Do this for the RGB format:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255,0,0")]
public override Color BackColor { get { return base.BackColor; } set { base.BackColor = value; } }
```

Comment: [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255,0,0")]
Works terrific! Thank you very much

Comment: However, the "public override Color BackColor { get; set; }" part makes my TextBo appear with a Black background.. only when I write it the long way: public override Color BackColor
  {
   get  { return(base.BackColor);  }
   set  { base.BackColor =value;  }
  } then it works ok.. why?

Comment: @Omer: the long way calls the base class version of `BackColor`, which actually changes the color (using Win32 magic). The short version is an auto-property and basically just stores the color in the derived class in a new field and does nothing with it.

Comment: the last issue(black BG) ight have happened because my project weas st to compile as .NET 2.0, and not 3.0 or more.. I think the short "get; set;" form appeared in .NET 3.0 **EDIT:** siride you are right. Changing the project to be .NET 3.5 id not help.. so I am reverting to the long form.. thank you

Comment: @Omer: if you compile for 2.0, then you'll get a compile error, rather than a black textbox. The problem does not have anything to do with which version of .NET you're using and instead has to do with how `BackColor` is actually implemented.

Comment: BTW why would someone give me -1 for this question? :/

Comment: Don't know, but it is fixed! Will you accept my answer?

Comment: Thank you.. And sorry about the "Accept" - I was not aware of that in this website.. I did now :) Thank you very much all